# zabbix server pushing data to database

Tags: database, monitoring, zabbix

Is it possible to set zabbix server for oftener pushing data to database? We found out in postgres log that zabbix server pushes data to database every 5 seconds. How to update this interval for more realtime monitoring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably change `CONFIG_HISTSYNCER_FREQUENCY` in `src/zabbix_server/server.c` to a lower value. It is 5 seconds by default.

Comment: We can't find this file. 'server.c'  either directory src in zabbix.

Comment: You need to download a Zabbix source distribution from http://www.zabbix.com/download.php, make the change and recompile Zabbix server according to instructions at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install . If you installed Zabbix server from packages, then you should consult with your package manager documentation on how apply a custom patch.